# Adjusting height of ScrollViewer to full height in wp8.1

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I have a scrollViewer

```
    <ScrollViewer Padding="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="2" Name="thumbView"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230" Height="606">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="scrollStackPanel"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

The problem is for Windows application i want the height to fill entire height of screen. Right now 606 is good for 13" monitors but for big monitors its half way only. I want it to spread to entire screen height. How can i do it?

Comment: You shouldn't specify a `Height`, remove it and `your `ScrollViewer` will take up all the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` should work.

And this part you should delete.

```
Margin="0,86,0,0" Width="230" Height="606"
```

Try this and tell me if its work.

Greetings!

Comment: You don't need to set either `HorizontalAlignment` or `VerticalAlightment`. Their default value is `Stretch`.

Comment: The problem is, i want to set it width 230 and on right side of screen. Its just height that i want to stretch. If i remove them, it disappears and dosen't stretch like a Grid

Comment: Ok i removed height and only using VerticalAlignment="Stretch" worked alone, Thanks. It seems the default doesn't work for ScrollViewer. u have to specify